# Cannot get headers in flask app through nginx-gunicorn

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

I' m trying to get real ip addresses of users who visit the site. 
For that, I'd like to add custom authorization for API service. Using headers for both cases seems like a good idea.

The problem is that I cannot get custom headers in my flask app that is served by nginx and gunicorn web-servers. Getting 'remote_addr' headers returns only 127.0.0.1 IP address despite the fact I post from outer network, not from localhost.

Here are my configuration files:

part of nginx config //1.14.2

```
location / {
        # forward application requests to the gunicorn server
        proxy_read_timeout 30s;
        proxy_send_timeout 30s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header CLIENT-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

part of gunicorn config //20.0.4

```
[program:wapp]
command=/home/deeslo/processor/venv/bin/gunicorn -b localhost:5000 -w 4 microservice:app
directory=/home/deeslo/processor
user=deeslo
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```

When I check headers, I don't see there neither X-Real-IP/CLIENT-IP from nginx nor other custom headers that I sent in flask make response headers.

What did I miss?
Could not solve it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, that was totally my fault.

The problem was I was debugging the application in my IDE where the application was running through embedded web-server, not nginx.

The solution above works perfect, I can get User IP address in flask app with:

`request.header['X-Real-IP']`